# Xcode 5 unit test seeing wrong class

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcode5, jsonmodel

I am running into a bizarre situation where a unit test's execution is behaving differently than the normal execution of a piece of code.

In particular, I am using a library called JSONModel, and when I am attempting to deserialize an object from a JSON string, one line in particular is causing problems when I step through the executing test case:

```
if ( [[property.type class] isSubclassOfClass:[JSONModel class]] ) ...
```

If I put a breakpoint before (or after) this line and execute:

```
expr [[property.type class] isSubclassOfClass:[JSONModel class]]
```

...in the debugger, it prints `\x01` as the value (i.e. true), however when I actually step the instruction pointer, it behaves as though it is false, going instead into the else block. Again, typing the expression into the debugger again shows it as true even still.

I'm curious if anyone has seen similar behavior before and has any suggestions as to what could possibly be going wrong. I'm quite certain I'm not including different definitions for anything, unless Xcode has different internal cocoa class implementations for testing.

**Update:** Here's some even weirder evidence: I've added some `NSLog` statements to get an idea for how the execution is seeing things. If I log `property.type.superclass` I get `JSONModel` back (as expected); *however* if I log `property.type.superclass == [JSONModel class]` I get `false`!

To me this is indicating that the JSONModel the unit test execution is seeing is somehow a different JSONModel class that I'm seeing at runtime (and what it should be seeing). However, how that is happening I can't figure out.

Could this be caused by a forward class declaration or something like that?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to compare classes for equality, given that a lot of tricks are played with class "families".  (What happens when you do `po [property.type class]`?)  (And any reason for using `isSubClassOfClass` instead of `isKindOfClass`?)

Comment: `isKindOfClass` is for comparing instances, however what I (or rather JSONModel) has is a value of type `Class`. Therefore I can't use `isKindOfClass` or `isMemberOfClass`. As for `po [property.type class]`, I get `Product`, which is the JSONModel-derived class I am testing.

Comment: You're comparing the class of property.type to the class of JSONModel.  isKindOfClass should work just fine if you use property.type vs [property.type class].

Comment: Unfortunately this craziness is still happening even if NSClassFromString() is used ...

Comment: I'm seeing this in my unit tests also. I think it stems from the test project referencing the library under test and the test host app also referencing the library under test. Try class_getImageName(property.type.superclass) and class_getImageName([JSONModel class]) and check what the sources of the classes are.

Answer (score 3):

Well I seem to have discovered a "solution" by experimentation. It turns out if I replace `[JSONModel class]` with `NSClassFromString(@"JSONModel")` it works swimmingly!

Now *why* this is I cannot say, and will give the answer to whoever can explain it!

Comment: If JSONModel is present in a library module in addition to your main code then the version you're referencing may be from the library module, and comparing class == class will fail.

Comment: I considered that, but it's all in one big happy project. No external libraries.

Comment: Add the class you're testing to the Unit test target as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, here's what was happening.

As expected with this kind of behaviour, it was an issue with the class being duplicated. As with you, `[instance class]` and `NSClassFromString` would return different values. However, the class were identical in all points : same ivar, same methods (checked with the obj runtime). No warning was displayed at compile, link and/or runtime

In my case, the tests were about a static library used in my main application (Bar.app).

Basically, I had 3 targets:

- `libFoo`
- `libFooTests`
- `Bar.app`

The tests were performing on the device, and not on simulator. As such, they needed to be **logic tests**, and not **unit tests**, and had to be loaded into an application. The bundle loader was my main app, `Bar.app`. 
Only additional linker flag was `-ObjC`

Now, `Bar.app` was linking `libFoo`. 
It turns out, `libFooTests` was also linking `libFoo`.
When injecting `libFooTests` in the test host (`Bar.app`), symbols were duplicated, but no warning were presented to me. This is how this particular class got duplicated.

Simply removing `libFoo` from the list of libraries to link against in `libFooTests` did the trick.